# Replacing default OpenSSL with built one from sources(with FIPS) and linking

Tags: c, ubuntu, openssl

For some reasons I need it to be done, here is how I tried to achieve this :
 1. Download sources of FIPS and OpenSSL
 2. Unpack and in FIPS src directory :

```
./config -d
make
sudo make install
```

3. After that in OpenSSL sources directory :

```
./config -d fips shared
make depend
make
sudo make install
```

I want to use OpenSSL 1.0.2j with FIPS as dynamic library in my application on Ubuntu, not using linking with path parameters but default OpenSSL path installed in Ubuntu (replace old OpenSSL with new one)

Comment: Why "cmake" tag? If you want `find_package` to find manually installed OpenSSL, you need to hint this command about install location. E.g. via setting *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* variable.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance... What is the problem, or what is the question?